# 'which' function in R returns row = 1 while the matched value is in row 2?

Tags: r, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have a translation table where I am using `do.call(paste, input) %in% do.call(paste, big_translation_table)`.

It returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Then I am using `which` function to find the index, but it always returns `1`.

Here is a small example:

```
test1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b=2, c = "r", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b=c(2,10), c = c("r","p"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

which(do.call(paste, test1) %in% do.call(paste, test2))
```

returns 1 and it's ok, now let's test with:

```
test1 <- data.frame(a = 2, b=10, c = "p", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
which(do.call(paste, test1) %in% do.call(paste, test2))
```

returns 1 too.
I think it should return 2.

Comment: By switching `test1` and `test2` you will get want you expect for the sample data, i.e., `which(do.call(paste, test2) %in% do.call(paste, test1))` returns `2` for the 2nd test case. However, `do.call(paste, ...)` is not the best approach IMHO to lookup multiple values, see my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47971015/3817004):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%in%` is just a logical test of whether (in this case) `test1` appears in `test2`, not on a case by case basis. I think you just want `==`:

```
test1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b=2, c = "r", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> which(do.call(paste, test1) == do.call(paste, test2))
[1] 1
```

Then:

```
test1 <- data.frame(a = 2, b=10, c = "p", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> which(do.call(paste, test1) == do.call(paste, test2))
[1] 2
```

Comment: And it is well documented in the R documentation. See `match` and `%in%`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has asked to find the row number in the translatation table `test2` for matches in *all* columns. He is pasting all columns together to create a natural key for looking up `test1` in `test2`.

Instead of repeatedly pasting the columns together it is more efficient to do a *join*. The `data.table` package has the `which` parameter which returns the  row numbers:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test2)[setDT(test1), on = names(test1), which = TRUE]
```

> ```
> [1] 2
> ```

for the 2nd test case.

If it is necessary to be explicit on the columns to be used in the join, we can write

```
setDT(test2)[setDT(test1), on = .(a, b, c), which = TRUE]
```